# Using git through wsl (ubuntu) & windows terminal, how do you change the default branch name to main?

Tags: git, ubuntu, branch, wsl-2, windows-terminal

Using git through wsl (ubuntu) & windows terminal, how do you change the default branch name to main?

I've already tried:

```
git config --global init.defaultBranch main
```

and the setting "init.defaultbranch=main" is there when I look at:

```
git config --global --list
```

but when I try to make a new git init in a brand new folder it still uses master...
Any ideas?

Comment: As you saw, Git versions before 2.28 simply don't have this as an option (they ignore any `init.defaultBranch` setting). Note, though, that you can simply run `git checkout -b main` after `git init` creates the empty repository, including in both the old and new Git versions.

Answer (score 4):

So it turns out you need git version 2.28 or higher. I had git version 2.25.1 even though I just installed git a few months ago.
For Ubuntu it seems you have to jump through a few hoops to get the lastest version.

This is what I tried

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

After that you can check your version using:

```
git --version
```

If you added the global setting in the code from my question you should be good to go.

Comment: This answer still works as of 2023-04-21. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 in WSL2 (my remote web host uses this version and I am emulating its environment on my local), and that has git 2.17.1. This answer got me to 2.40.0